# Insurance Premium that covers only the loss and not the profit

Tags: utility

For example: The utility function is ln(W), where W refers to the Wealth level. The initial wealth is $10,000  $ and you have a equal chance of winning and losing $1000.

What if the insurance policy only covers the loss, how are you willing to pay for the insurance premium?

Need some guidance on solving this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you end up with either $10000-p$ or $11000-p$  instead of either $9000$ or $11000$. You must solve for $p$ in
$$\frac 12\ln(10000-p)+\frac12\ln(11000-p) = \frac12\ln 9000+\frac12\ln 11000$$
or equivalently
$$ (10000-p)(11000-p)=9000\cdot 11000$$
whihc is a quadratic in $p$ where one of the roots is between $0$ and $1000$ (and the other makes both factors on the left negative and can be ignored). It turns out that the premium will eat more than half of your hoped-for profit ...

Comment: I understand the quadratic eqn part but why do you equate the expected utility with insurance to expected utility without insurance?

Comment: @lakesh in expected utility theory, the  rational decision maker will make the decision by attempting to maximize the expected value of utility under different scenarios. By equating the expected utility w/ and w/o insurance, one find the breakeven point where the rational decision maker will accept or decline the insurance.